# Require JS with Bootstrap-ui

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-ui-bootstrap, requirejs-define

I would like to know how I can incorporate boostrap-ui as a dependency(require JS) in order to work with angular. 

 **Current Issue** I face is that when injecting the dependency and when i do console log on bootstrapUi it returns undefined.

Current code for app config:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "../",
  paths: {
    "angular": "assets/libs/angular.min",
    "jquery": "assets/libs/jquery-2.2.2",
    "bootstrapUi": "assets/libs/ui-bootstrap-1.3.1.min"
  },
  "shim": {
      "angular": {
        deps: ["jquery"],
        exports: "angular"
      },
       "bootstrapUi": {
           deps: ["angular"],
           exports: "bootstrapUi"
       }
  }
});

require(["app.main", "app.controllers"], function(app) {
    app.init();
});
```

Current code for App controller:

```
define(["app.main", "bootstrapUi"], function (app, bootstrapUi) {
    app.controller("loginCtrl", function () {
        bootstrapUi.alert("Hello Wolrd!");
    });
});
```

When above is called I receive error ***"Cannot read property 'alert' of undefined"***

What I'm trying to achieve is using the dependency in order to create a modal.

Answer (score 1):

Angular-ui-boostrap creates a module called 'ui.bootstrap'.
In order to use it with requireJS, you have to require the javascript and then add the module it creates as a dependency of your angular application.

```
define(['angular', 'bootstrapUi'], function(){

    angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

});
```

To use the modal, follow de documentation: [ui-bootstrap modal docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).

Comment: Once i have setup the code you have recommended how do i call it into my controller ? please refer to my above code  App controller. Do i pass in 'bootstapUi' or $ and how do i call functions of bootstrap i.e. .show or .alert

Comment: Have you checked the documentation I linked?

[Take a look in their example](http://plnkr.co/edit/04Ux84nrtsePvdPCiBtg?p=preview)

Comment: I have looked at the example u have provided. When i call something very simple i.e. $scope.alert i receive '$scope.alert' is not a function. I have injected scope through the controller but still unable to use it